# Difference between CNAME and SUBDOMAIN

Tags: dns, subdomain, cname

What is the difference between a CNAME and a Subdomain?

I understand that the a cname (the left side of a domain) can point to the domain, so you can two different urls point to the same address, ie.

**ex1.mydomain.com** - if setup as a CNAME can return the IP of **mydomain.com**

If ex1.mydomain.com is setup as a subdomain, does it have a different IP?

Another question is what should the ideal setup be in this situation:

> I have IP1:80 for a web app
>
> I have IP2:80 for another app

Can I point both of these IPs to the same A record, with perhaps a different cname or subdomain?

Thanks for any help?

Comment: belongs on webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CNAME is agnostic about name topology - it simply provides a way to alias a lookup for one name into a lookup for another name.  So it may be in a subdomain context, or not.

Your second question doesn't make any sense to me.  An A record maps from a domain name to (a single) IP address.  So normally, in this situation, you'd have two domain names with an A record for each.

Comment: Ok, I understand a little more about CNAMES.  Can I do this with a subdomain though:  mydomain.com (IP1), ex1.mydomain.com (IP2)

Comment: @GregGamm - yes - two A records.